# take characters after spaces in java

Tags: java, regex, string, token

I have a string and it has two words with 3 spaces between them. For example: `"Hello   Java"`. I need to extract "Java" from this string. I searched for regex and tokens, but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is split the string by the space and get the second index since Java is after the first space.  You said it has 3 spaces so you can just do:

```
string.split("   ")[1];
```

In your case, if string is equal to Hello Java with three spaces, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this, but which you choose depends on how you may expect your input to vary. If you can assume there will always be exactly 3 spaces in the string, all sequential, then just use the indexOf method to locate the first space, add 3 to that index, and take a substring with the resulting value. If you're unsure how many sequential spaces there will be, use lastIndexOf and add 1. You can also use the split method mentioned in another solution.

For instance:

```
String s = "Hello   Java";
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
System.out.println(s);
```